# Is there a name for a factorial-like falling product which uses an arbitrary step $x \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of 1.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, factorial, gamma-function

We can define the factorial for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ as the follows.

$n!=n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \cdots$

This can be thought of as a repeating falling product in steps of 1.

In fact, the notion of multifactorial can be similarly defined as the follows (shown below are double and triple factorials)

\begin{align*}
    n!! &=n\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-4)\cdot(n-6)\dots && \textit{Terminates with 2 or 1}\\
    n!!! &=n\cdot(n-3)\cdot(n-6)\cdot(n-9)\dots && \textit{Terminates with 3, 2 or 1}\\
    & \vdots
\end{align*}

My question is,

Consider a function , say $n^{(k)}=n \cdot (n-k) \cdot (n-2k) \cdots\ \textit{Terminates with largest q such that (n-qk) > 0}$

for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0, k \in \mathbb{R}$

Is such a function even well defined? If yes then, is there any reference where I can read more about such a function? Does it have any common name?

Of course $n^{(1)}$ (i.e. n!) can be generalized for real entries of $n$ using the gamma function $\Gamma(n)$. Is it possible to generalize the function $n^{k}$ for real entries of $n$ as well?

I just came across idea when writing my maths undergraduate project, but I wasn't able to find any references online nor on Stackexchange.
Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: There is such a function since you just defined it

Comment: Ah yes of course. Sorry for the ambiguity what I meant was, has it already been discussed in maths literature. Or is there some common name for such a function. Since I wanted to find out more about it. I've edited this in the post now.

Comment: I would not use the notation you show here since it is very ambiguous. Coming across $n!!$ my first thought would be that you mean $(n!)!$ which gives a completely different result.

Comment: @Ipnorm $n!!$ is standard notation. OP did not invent it and despite looking ambiguous, in practice you never actually encounter $(n!)!$, so it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [generalized falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Generalizations), sometimes called a [multifactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html) when the step size is a positive integer. [OEIS has a page](https://oeis.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Multifactorial) that's light on details but links to the multifactorial sequences. Beyond the double factorial, they do not show up much. I'm not immediately coming up with interesting properties to investigate. Maybe a multifactorial analogue of exponential generating functions?

Comment: Thanks! I think this is it. Does there exist any extension of this for real/complex entries too? Its not mentioned in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Analogues with real or complex step sizes would just be a certain type of generalized falling factorial. Obviously they exist and are well-defined. They simply don't show up often enough to have well-developed names and theory behind them. If you had an actual use for them that would be different.